# How to get that idea to solve this PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following System:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=f_A(A_0,B_0)u+f_B(A_0,B_0)v+D_A\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=g_A(A_0,B_0)u+g_B(A_0,B_0)v+D_B\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2},
$$
where $(A_0,B_0)$ is a stable equilibrium and $A(x,t)=A_0+u(x,t), B(x,t)=B_0+v(x,t)$ is the linearization at this point. $f$ and $g$ are some reaction functions and $D_A,D_B$ some diffusion constants.

We can write this in vector form, using $w=(u,v)$, $D=\begin{pmatrix}D_A & 0\\0 & D_B\end{pmatrix}$ and $J=\begin{pmatrix}f_A(A_0,B_0) & f_B(A_0,B_0)\\g_A(A_0,B_0) & g_B(A_0,B_0)\end{pmatrix}$ being
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=Jw+D\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}.
$$
As boundary conditions, we have
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}_{|0}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}_{|L}=0.
$$

> > It is said that
> >     $$
> > w(x,t)=w_0e^{\lambda t}\cos kx
> > $$
> >     solves the system. How do I get that idea? For me it falls out of the clouds...

Comment: Well, there is an analogy which might help you internalize this ansatz. It comes from solving linear homogeneous ODEs: exponents and polynomials lie in the class of functions which is closed under linear operations and differentiation. Euler had a nice guess and since this moment we look for solutions almost always this way. The ansatz in your equation is just further version of this guess: "why not try to do the same way as we did in ODEs, looking for solutions as exponents?"

Comment: Indeed, the Ansatz reminds me on the situation of a linear homogeneous second order ODE in case we have the characteristic equation $am^2+bm+c=0$ with a complex conjugated pair $m_{1,2}=\alpha\pm i\beta$ as solution such that $y=e^{\alpha x}(c_1\sin(\beta x)+c_2\cos(\beta x))$ is the solution; here it seems to be something similar... however, not sure where $w_0,\lambda,t,k$ come from, but it looks similar.

Comment: Yeah :) but here is one addition: for example, if you have equation $u_{tt} = c^2 u_xx$ and plug $u(x, t) = e^{wx+kt}$ in it, divide by $e^{wx+kt}$ you'll get a special equation called _dispersion equation_ : $k^2 = c^2 w^2$. Note that $k$ and $w$ could be complex numbers. Any combination of $k$ and $w$ which satisfies this equation can be used to form solution of wave equation -- there is continuum of exponential functions which satisfy this equation! However, you need to apply boundary conditions to get less wild set of basis functions.

Comment: We do we get the $e^{\lambda t}$ from? $\lambda$ seems to be the real part of the complex conjugated pair of solution of the char. equation. But why times t and not times x as it is in the Ode case?

Comment: We have both! $w_0 e^{\lambda t} \cos kx $ is just another way (not) to write $w_0 e^{\lambda t} e^{ikx}$.

Comment: Maybe can you give me a link where I can see the ansatz in its general from?

Comment: In your case the most general form would be $e^{\lambda t + ikx} \cdot \mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is a constant vector. I don't think that a reference is really needed here, but you may start from this http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_1.pdf .

Comment: I just wonder how we get from the general ansatz in ODE case, i.e. $y(x)=e^{ax}(c_1\sin(bx)+c_2\cos(bx))$ where $a\pm bi$ are the solutions of the characteristic equation, to the ansatz used here.

Comment: By the power of analogy. This allows us to find some solutions of this system. The rest is done by proving that these solutions are enough for constructing all other solutions. So, again, analogy gives us a guess and this guess happens to be a solution.

Comment: But there must be some statement like: "if we have a pde of this form, make the ansatz..." :-)

Comment: But that's the different question :) The problem is that I've never had a separate PDE course that taught us such things and we learned them from mathematical physics course. I think that almost any PDE book or notes cover this ansatz if it has section about solving linear PDEs.

Comment: Ok. Because for me it is still unclear how to get from factor $e^{ax}$ in ode case to factor $e^{\lamda t}$ here.

Comment: I don't understand your last question at all. And frankly speaking I don't understand why is it so important.

Comment: Probably, it is not that important. As I said before, I see some similarity to the general solution $y(x)=e^{ax}(c_1\sin(bx)+c_2\cos(bx))$ for a linear homogeneous ODE of order 2. But, to be honest, I do not see exactly how this is connected with the ansatz in the case here of a pde. You wrote "by the power of analogy" and that the ansatz is something like $e^{\lambda t+ikx}\cdot v$. So, obviously, in this ansatz, we do not have the factor $e^{ax}$ but $e^{\lambda t+ikx}$. I just wondered where this comes frome. But I guess this would need the theory of pde to get more concrete insight.

Comment: Maybe my confusion comes from the fact that the first ansatz (for the ODE) is only depending on x, and the second one (for the pde) depends on x and t.

Comment: In PDE we have two independent variables, so it would be too restrictive to have a solution that depends only on one variable. The reason why we use $e^{at}$ in linear ODE is that because it behaves very nice w.r.t. differentiations and additions (and because our equation behaves very nice w.r.t. linear combinations of functions). The same holds for linear PDEs: $e^{at}$ is as good solution as $e^{bx}$, why not construct $a^{at+bx}$ and check, is it good for solving such equations or systems? This is my intuition. I've tried to do my best, but language barrier seems to be my worst enemy now :)